# ipyauth with jupyter: google callback results in MIME type mismatch

Tags: javascript, python, html, ipython, jupyter

I am trying to get ipyauth running inside a jupyter notebook as described [here](https://medium.com/@olivier.borderies/oauth2-from-inside-a-jupyter-notebook-5f5e61ec5d38). However when clicking on the 'Sign In' button, no pop-up appears. Instead the callback runs into MIME type conflicts.

Two weeks ago, I have been able to run [this demo notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gitlab.com/oscar6echo/ipyauth/raw/master/notebooks/demo-ipyauth-google.ipynb), but a (not related) problem forced me to reinstall ipyauth, and now I run into this issue. I have set up a new Anaconda3 environment and installed ipyauth as described in [this tutorial](https://oscar6echo.gitlab.io/ipyauth/guide/install.html#classic-notebook). My jupyter notebook version is 5.7.6 and all necessary extensions are enabled, as listed in the [dev-install section](https://oscar6echo.gitlab.io/ipyauth/dev/dev_install.html#check-extensions).

Opening a console shows the following error, after clicking on the 'Sign In' button:

```
Script from http://localhost:8888/callback/assets/util.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch
```

In Firefox the console also states the conflict is due to "text/html". The lines given in the console before the MIME mismatch are:

```
btn_main clicked widget_box.js:84:20
start startAuthFlow widget_auth.js:38:4
name=google, isIframeMode=true widget_auth.js:46:4
paramsModel widget_util.js:4:4
{"name":"google","url_params":{"response_type":"token","client_id":"729266704353-i9eueh2db24if69v2ohj4brfa94c48ns.apps.googleusercontent.com","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8888/callback/","scope":"profile openid","include_granted_scopes":"false"}} widget_util.js:5:4
paramsFull widget_util.js:4:4
{"name":"google","authorize_endpoint":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth","url_params":{"response_type":"token","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8888/callback/","client_id":"729266704353-i9eueh2db24if69v2ohj4brfa94c48ns.apps.googleusercontent.com","scope":"profile openid","access_type":"online","state":"google,iframe,fbixswbono","include_granted_scopes":"false","prompt":"none"},"scope_separator":" ","isJWT":false} widget_util.js:5:4
authUrl widget_util.js:4:4
"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fcallback%2F&client_id=729266704353-i9eueh2db24if69v2ohj4brfa94c48ns.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile%20openid&access_type=online&state=google%2Ciframe%2Cfbixswbono&include_granted_scopes=false&prompt=none" widget_util.js:5:4
start buidReadMessage widget_auth.js:80:4
----------- startAuthFlowInIframe widget_util.js:4:4
undefined widget_util.js:5:4
```

Other than that, the notebook does not react to the button click.

Do I have to change something in my jupyter config file? Can I somehow find out where this error is exactly coming from? Is this a bug in ipyauth, or am I doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of `ipyauth` (0.2.5), the `Content-Type` header of the `assets/util.js` and `assets/main.js` files are not set.

A fix for this is to follow the [Dev Install section](https://oscar6echo.gitlab.io/ipyauth/dev/dev_install.html) of the docs, installing all necessary extensions, but before you run `jupyter notebook` to open the notebook interface, change `ipyauth/ipyauth/ipyauth_callback/server_extension.py` to

```
import os
import mimetypes
from notebook.base.handlers import IPythonHandler
from notebook.utils import url_path_join


def load_jupyter_server_extension(nb_app):
    web_app = nb_app.web_app

    web_app.settings['jinja2_env'].loader.searchpath += [
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', 'assets'),
    ]

    class CallbackHandler(IPythonHandler):
        """
        """

        def get(self, path):
            """
            """
            nb_app.log.info("in CallbackHandler with path={}".format(path))
            self.write(self.render_template('index.html'))

    class CallbackAssetsHandler(IPythonHandler):
        """
        """

        def get(self, path):
            """
            """
            nb_app.log.info("in CallbackAssetsHandler with path={}".format(path))
            mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(path)
            self.set_header('Content-Type', mime_type)
            self.write(self.render_template(path))

    host_pattern = '.*$'
    base_url = web_app.settings['base_url']

    web_app.add_handlers(
        host_pattern,
        [(url_path_join(base_url, '/callback/assets/(.*)'), CallbackAssetsHandler),
        (url_path_join(base_url, '/assets/(.*)'), CallbackAssetsHandler),
        (url_path_join(base_url, '/callback(.*)'), CallbackHandler),
        (url_path_join(base_url, '/callback.html(.*)'), CallbackHandler),
        ]
    )

    nb_app.log.info("ipyauth callback server extension enabled")
```

This adds the correct `Content-Type` to those two javascript files.

I'll open an issue on the ipyauth repo regarding this problem. Hopefully a more robust solution will be added to the master branch soon so we can use this tool in production